# MIPS MARS: Weird bug with floating points

Tags: assembly, floating-point, mips32, mars-simulator

I'm getting a weird bug when I try to set a float register to a float in a label. I'm basically trying to calculate the average of the sorted array I created that has 5 values. I add the five values together and then I attempt to divide the float by 5 with the $f9 register.

The problem is that whenever the l.s instruction is called, the $f9 register is set to the last value in my array, which screws up the math of getting the average.

```
.data
#STACK
    floatArray:     .float 0.0 : 4
    five:           .float 5

...

getAverage:
    #GET ALL FLOATS
    la      $s0, floatArray   #Set $s0 to start of array
    l.s     $f4, 0($s0)     #Get float from array
    l.s     $f5, 4($s0)     #Get float from array
    l.s     $f6, 8($s0)     #Get float from array
    l.s     $f7, 12($s0)        #Get float from array
    l.s     $f8, 16($s0)        #Get float from array

    #ADD ALL FLOATS AND DIVIDE
    add.s       $f5, $f5, $f4   
    add.s       $f6, $f6, $f5       
    add.s       $f7, $f7, $f6       
    add.s       $f8, $f8, $f7   
    l.s         $f9, five       #Get float from label
    div.s       $f12,$f8, $f9
```

At l.s when I debug, the $f9 register is set to the last float in the array instead of the float 5 I set in the label.

[image]

Comment: You only have space for 4 floats in your array but you use 5. So I guess you are overwriting `five` in code you did not show.

Comment: @Jester Oh wow, yeah I think you're right. Sometimes I amaze myself.